# How to write the Code for "Click on the Link" in Robot Frame Work?

Tags: robotframework

When Click on the Declare Failure Link, using Click Link Code:

```
span[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFailureDetails_lblDtcCode_9']
```

the Error is Displaying as

> Link with locator
>   '//span[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFailureDetails_lblDtcCode_9']' not
>   found.

[Robot framework](https://robotframework.org/)

Comment: Fixed code formatting added blockquote for error and also link to robot framework site.

Comment: Have you tried the docs? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/#user-guide

Answer (score 1):

[Click link](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link) can only be used to click on link (e.g. an `<a>` element). If you need to click on a `<span>`, use [Click Element](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Element).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Click link keyword can break for other elements, I use the most generic way which is Click Element.

```
*** Setting ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
    Click Element    id:ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFailureDetails_lblDtcCode_9
```

Instead of Id, you may also use the xpath. In this case you will have:

```
Click Element    xpath:.//span[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_grdFailureDetails_lblDtcCode_9']
```

For more information, refer to https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html